# What does this code actually do?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have recently been employed at an office where they use a lot of php in their work, most of my development background is HTML, CSS, Jquery, Wordpress and Angularjs, I have an idea behind the logic of some of php but was just wondering if anyone can enlighten me as to what this code below actually means/does?

```
return (isset($rs[0][0]) ? $rs[0][0] : "");
```

It is located within this function that calls the database and returns values.

```
function get_temp($table, $field){
    global $db;
    $sql="select $field from $table";
    $rs=$db->select($sql);
    return (isset($rs[0][0]) ? $rs[0][0] : "");
}
```

I feel that is selecting one value from an array within an array but I cannot find any sources to confirm this so was hoping someone on here could help me out or at least point me in the right direction if I am wrong. The reason I believe this is the case is because if I pass the `$field` variable more than one result it will always only return the first one, if this is the case it would also be helpful to me if someone could suggest a way to get all of the results, whenever I simply try:

```
return $rs
```

It simply returns "Array".

Comment: It calls the database, returns some data and checks to see if certain data is returned. Then it returns that data or no data at all.

Comment: So I had basically answered my own question? how would I go about returning all of the values instead of just one then?

Comment: Return all with: return $rs;

Comment: I tried this and all that would return to the page would simply be the word "Array"

Comment: Once you have `$rs` you have to parse the array.

Comment: okay, thanks very much!

Comment: See also [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [`isset()` vs. `empty()` vs. `is_null()`](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(isset($rs[0][0]) ? $rs[0][0] : "");
```

This is a ternary operator. It does a check if `$rs[0][0]` is set. If yes it will make the function return `$rs[0][0]`'s value, if not it will return an empty string.

You could translate it to an if statement like this:

```
if (isset($rs[0][0])) {
    return $rs[0][0];
}
return "";
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact the method isset will check is the value is null.

Then it is simply a ternary operator, returning the value of the variable if it is not empty and an empty string if the value of the var is empty.